# How to omit commented lines using RegEx

Tags: visual-studio, regex

can somebody tell me how to avoid commented lines when using a regular expression in Visual Studio?  I tried `^[^//]*` but it deosn't work.

For example, I want to omit following line when I search:

```
//Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(:?//[^\n]*|/\*.*\*/)
```

**update** added some sample code

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Regex commentsFilter = new Regex(@"(:?//[^\n]*|/\*.*\*/)");
            string sample = ""
                + "a\n"
                + "//b\n"
                + "/*c*/\n"
                + "d";
            string filteredSample = commentsFilter.Replace(sample, "");
            string[] lines = filteredSample.Split('\n');
            foreach (string line in lines) {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the "Prevent Match" syntax "~()" in Visual Studio:

```
^~(//).*
```

Perhaps you want to allow optional spaces or tabs at the beginning of lines not to match:

```
^:b~*(//).*
```

For information the ~() operator is a negative lookahead assertion, in conventional regex syntax (rather than VS) this would be written as:

```
^\s*(?!//).*
```